# Как правильно обратиться к полю Speed объекта other в OnTriggerEnter?

Tags: unity3d

```
    public float Speed;
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {      
       if(other.gameObject.tag == "backCar"){
            Speed = other.gameObject.Speed;       
        }
```

Выводит "error CS1061: Type `UnityEngine.GameObject' does not contain a definition for`Speed' and no extension method `Speed' of type`UnityEngine.GameObject' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?"

p.s. этот скрипт висит на 2 объектах. когда вторая машина подъезжает к первой, она должна сделать скорость такой же

Comment: у него нет поля speed,есть просто переменная speed,которую вы могли хоть mass назвать,она от этого не станет управлять массой

Comment: то есть, я не смогу узнать скорость машины через другой объект?

Answer (score 1):

у GameObject нет поля Speed. Вам необходимо получить ваш компонент на этом объекте. Н-р так (строчка является примером не защищенным от провала получения необходимого компонента)

```
Speed = other.gameObject.GetComponent<ТипВашегоКомпонентаСоСкоростью>().Speed;
```

Comment: не робит... триггер срабатывает, но скорость не берется у первой машины

Comment: @кириллбалашов, ну так дебажте. Чему равна скорость у второй машины? Какое именно значение присваивается при срабатывании триггера?

Comment: ладно, я вообще по-другому делал... хотел оптимизировать..в другой раз, но все равно спасибо)